# SANDBOX - Access webservice getting below error - added my machine IP in the Remote Site Detail

Tags: apex, visualforce, webservices, wsdl2apex

ERROR

The requested URL could not be retrieved

---

While trying to retrieve the URL:

The following error was encountered: 
• Access Denied. 
Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect.

Your cache administrator is support@salesforce.com.

---

Generated Wed, 30 Jul 2014 16:45:09 GMT by proxy-sjl.net.salesforce.com (squid)

Comment: Hi, I am getting same error. Pl share with me what was the fix?

Answer (score 2):

Does this happen at all times ? The last 2 lines sort of indicate this is a salesforce issue, and possibly not related to your configuration.

Your best bet is to log a case to salesforce support, they have access to internal logs and details that can shed more light on this.